# How to get TypeChain to generate types for Vyper contracts

Tags: typescript, blockchain, solidity, hardhat, vyper

Typechain generates types for Solidity contracts but not for Vyper contracts. I see that *.dbg.json file are generated for each corresponding *.sol file but not for *.vy

Edited: generating types via cli: npx typechain --target=ethers-v5 './artifacts/contracts/**/+([a-zA-Z0-9_]).json' --out-dir "./typechain/" and importing the types in hardhat.d.ts did the trick. It seems that hardhat has a bug in generating types for hardhat. Came to this conclusion based on a discussion here: https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain/issues/146